# How to load a java script in blogspot (Dynamic theme)

Tags: javascript, load, blogger, blogspot

I want to load this java script in my blogspot but i am unable to find how to load using onload event in blogspot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body onload="loadSelector()">
        <form>  
            <select id="selectElementId"></select>
            <script>
                function loadSelector()
                {
                    var min = 2012,
                    max = 2021,
                    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

                    for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
                        var opt = document.createElement('option');
                        opt.value = i;
                        opt.innerHTML = i;
                        select.appendChild(opt);
                    }

                    select.value = new Date().getFullYear();
                }



            </script>

        </form>

        <button class="btn " id="check" type="button"><span    class="check"></span> Check</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea how i can use onload event in blogspot

PS: Above html script is working fine i only need it to work inside blogspot

Answer (score 0):

window.onload will be executed everytime a page is loaded. Just add your code inside it and it will work fine. Don't forget to parse it before you save it into the template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  alert('HELLO THERE !!); // Remove this. Just for checking if onload is working or not
  // Add your Code here

}
</script>
```

Try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
    {
    alert("show alert");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="show()">
</body>
```

Comment: hey the above code is not working in blogspot. if it helps, i am using a dynamic theme in my blogsopt.

Comment: Are you even getting an alert?

Comment: That's strange. Please check update answer and see if its working for u.

Comment: No its not working. I am sorry but have you tried those codes on blogger? is it working for you?

Comment: Yes. It is working fine at least for me. Could you share the Template by uploading it on Google Drive or something like that?

Comment: Are you using the dynamic theme

Answer (score 0):

If you poke around in the `blogger` object, you'll find an `addListener()` function that supports binding a callback to an event named `'updated'`.

The `'updated'` event appears to be reliably fired whenever an article is displayed.  However, the event is **undocumented** and unfortunately is fired before all the *Dynamic* theme DOM manipulation is complete.  Using the event reduces uncertainty, but you may still need to hack on a `setTimeout()` delay.

A less than perfect solution:

```js
const onArticleLoad = () => {
   const h1 = globalThis.document.querySelector('h1.entry-title');
   console.log('Article title:', h1.textContent.trim());
   };
globalThis.blogger.ui().addListener('updated', () =>
   globalThis.setTimeout(onArticleLoad, 1000));
```